# Trigger a macro on a specified colum once data is imported from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro on a newly imported data.
Scenario:
I have to import a sheet with 5 columns and the macro is supposed to be applied to columns B and C *ONLY*, right after importing the data -  I load a sheet using `Data -> Get Data` and specify the source. Once everything is loaded a new sheet is created and I need the macro to be applied while the data is loaded.

I tried running this:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
   MsgBox Sh.Cells(3, 2)
End Sub
```

And the pop-up shows an empty string thus the data is populated as a second step there.

Comment: You could try the `Workbook_NewSheet` event (in the ThisWorkbook code module).  You can check the new sheet to see if the content looks like your imported data.

Comment: It doesn't really work. I tried doing sth like this: MsgBox Sh.Cells(3, 2) and it shows me an empty string. I guess it's because the macro is triggered before the the data is populated into cells.

Comment: Any code should be added to your question.  It won't be useful in a comment.

Comment: [Query events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.afterrefresh) might be useful

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use it?

Comment: workbook_NewSheet isn't a great idea because you may add another sheets while working in the workbook (not imported ones), so I guess you can import the data as usual and after run a macro (ALT+F8) referencing  ActiveSheet.

If you need to do this in more automated form, so you can import via VBA bypassing power query editor

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Sample.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _

Answer (score -1):

can't comment but what about a while loop and wait until the last cell is populated. Then do your function